# ASP.net How to use dropdownlist for retriving data from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a button,dropdownlist,and gridview. and i want that when i select any option from dropdownlist and click button . then the releted data is show into gridview .i have a problem that the data show in gridview but gridview d'nt work with the button

my code is

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="E_NAME" DataValueField="E_ID">


        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [E_ID], [E_NAME] FROM [EMP_DETAIL]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [E_ID], [E_NAME], [E_CITY], [E_AGE], [E_DEPARTMENT] FROM [EMP_DETAIL] WHERE ([E_ID] = @E_ID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="E_ID" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="E_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E_ID" HeaderText="E_ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="E_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E_NAME" HeaderText="E_NAME" 
                SortExpression="E_NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E_CITY" HeaderText="E_CITY" 
                SortExpression="E_CITY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E_AGE" HeaderText="E_AGE" SortExpression="E_AGE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E_DEPARTMENT" HeaderText="E_DEPARTMENT" 
                SortExpression="E_DEPARTMENT" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

Comment: where is your .cs code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `AutoPostBack` property of Drop-down to `False` or remove it:-

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="E_NAME" DataValueField="E_ID">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Since, you need the results on button click, the form will be refreshed after button click and taking the selected value in drop-down.

Comment: My question is: how can I get the SelectedValue of the DropDownList in GridView  Clicking on the Button

Comment: Clicking the Button  should only display the SelectedValue of the DropDownList in gridview.

Comment: @Safin - Didn't get you. You want to show the `E_ID` in your gridview? but that is already displayed right? as the first column?

Comment: drodownlist selected value worked fine and displaying record in gridviw. but i want to select from dropdownlist then click on button, after that E_NAME, E_CITY, E_AGE, E_DEPARTMENT will display in gridview. Thanks

Comment: @Safin - For that only I asked you to turn off `AutoPostBack`, See initially you must be able to see all the records in the grid, now when you select any value from dropdown and click on button, you want only that selected employee data to be shown on grid right?

Comment: yes i want only that selected employee data to be shown on gridview

Comment: but how can i add "select" in dropdownlist becoz i want to keep disappear girdview until i select employee name from dropdownlist and click on button...

Comment: @Safin - Simply add a `ListItem` like this:- `asp:ListItem>-- pick one --</asp:ListItem>`

Comment: Dear Rahul,
Thank you very much...
Your Code worked... Really Really thank you very much..